# Quitar un espacio en blanco

Tags: r, regex

Tengo un df de este estilo

```
x <- data.frame(col=c("X 100", "X 200", "casa", "B", "X 150", "C","X234"))
```

```
col
1 X 100
2 X 200
3  casa
4     B
5 X 150
6     C
7  X234
```

Donde aparece X+ número quiero poner un guión entre ellos de forma que quede así

```
col
1 X-100
2 X-200
3  casa
4     B
5 X-150
6     C
7  X-234
```

Hago lo siguiente:

```
library("stringr")
x$col2 <-str_replace(x$col, "(\\X)(\\d{3})","\\1-\\2")
```

```
    col   col2
1 X 100 X -100
2 X 200 X -200
3  casa   casa
4     B      B
5 X 150 X -150
6     C      C
7  X234  X-234
```

Y se me queda ese espacio en blanco en medio que no consigo quitar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que tienes un problema de concepto y estás esperando un resultado que no va a ocurrir. Veamos un ejemplo bien simple:

```
str_replace("X 100", "(\\X)", "\\1")
[1] "X 100"
```

¿Cómo funciona el `str_replace()` en este ejemplo?:

1. Captura el patrón `\\X`, es decir solo la `X`
2. Luego. simplemente reemplaza ese patrón encontrado, por el nuevo, que es el valor capturado `\\1` es decir reemplaza solo la `X` por la `X`, el resto de la cadena que no se ajusta a este patrón no se modifica.

En tu caso, cuando haces esto:

```
str_replace(x$col, "(\\X)(\\d{3})","\\1-\\2")
```

Simplemente lo que haces es:

- reemplazar la `X` por ese mismo valor `\\1`
- reemplazar el número por `-\\2`, es decir el mismo número con un guión
- El resto de los datos se mantiene igual, no estas creando una nueva cadena estás cambiando alguna partes de la cadena original.

Lo que buscas podrías lograrlo si al patrón hiciera "match" completo, algo así:

```
str_replace(x$col, "(\\X).*(\\d{3})","\\1-\\2")
```

No es un cambio muy grande, pero logras que patrón englobe completamente lo que buscas reformular, es decir

- la `X`
- 0 o más caracteres
- un número de hasta 3 cifras

Todo lo anterior se reemplaza ahora sí por el nuevo patrón y con esto de deshaces del espacio.

Answer (score 1):

Si el número de dígitos que siguen después de la `x` es 3, entonces el código es perfecto.

Pero en el caso que el número de dígitos fuera distinto a 3. La expresión regular no sería la mejor.

Como en tu pregunta dices donde aparece una `X` y un número. Entonces lo correcto sería colocar primero una condición que indique que el elemento posee un número.

```
x <- data.frame(col=c("X 100", "X 200", "casa", "B", "X 150",
                      "C","X234", "Xaxo","X434545","aXioma"))
```

Estoy aumentando elementos, específicamente el `X434545` que posee más de 3 números. La solución en R base sería así.

```
ifelse(grepl("\\d", x$col), gsub("(X\\s+|X)", "X-", x$col), x$col)
```

Y con el paquete `stringr` sería así:

```
ifelse(str_detect(x$col, "\\d"), str_replace(x$col,"(X\\s+|X)", "X-"), x$col)
```

Espero, pueda servirte.

Comment: Genial, gracias. Aunque este método convierte en numero todo lo que no sea "X numero" en vez de dejar el dato original

Comment: No, deja a los datos que no son "X nùmero" en su formato original. En la condiciòn le digo que solo reemplace cuando encuentra dìgitos, sino es asì entonces lo deja como estaba (dato original).

Comment: tal como esta lo convierte en número, me he dado cuenta de que habría que añadir al df stringsAsFactors=F para que funcione bien.